# Why is "vacuum" pronounced [ˈvæ.kjuːm] and not [ˈvæ.kjuː.əm] when other -uum words like "continuum" retain the vowel?

Tags: pronunciation

Per the title, why did "vacuum" (apparently) suffer syncope when words like "continuum" did not?

Comment: More importantly, English spelling has only a nodding acquaintance with English pronunciation, and should not be expected to indicate how a word is to be pronounced. Like German gender, English pronunciation has to be learned along with the word.

Comment: +1 It seems that _vacuum_ is the odd word out when placed in a lineup with (for example) _continuum_, _individuum_, _menstruum_, and _residuum_. I don't know why the -uum in _vacuum_ came to be pronounced differently from the -uum in the others, but to judge from the pronunciation offered in John Walker's [_A Critical Pronouncing Dictionary, and Expositor of the English Language_](https://books.google.com/books?id=VqURAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA654&dq=%22a+preservative+that+which+prevents%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBmoVChMI2626k9rYxgIVAlGICh1gBAsz#v=onepage&q=vacuum&f=false) (1807), 'twas not always thus.

Comment: See also Thomas Sheridan, [_A General Dictionary of the English Language_](https://books.google.com/books?id=_omG4cbLfRsC&pg=PT181&dq=%22a+preservative+that+which+prevents%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI2626k9rYxgIVAlGICh1gBAsz#v=onepage&q=vacuum&f=false) (1780) and Stephen Jones, [_Sheridan Improved: A General Pronouncing and Explanatory Dictionary of the English Language_](https://books.google.com/books?id=sDVAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT606&dq=%22a+preservative+that+which+prevents%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCWoVChMI2626k9rYxgIVAlGICh1gBAsz#v=onepage&q=vacuum&f=false) (1798).

Comment: By the way, _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) continues to list a three-syllable pronunciation of _vacuum_ as a secondary (or tertiary) pronunciation of the word, and as late as _Webster's New International Dictionary_ (1909), the dictionary doesn't even bother to provide a pronunciation independent of its prescribed syllable division, presumably because the people at Merriam-Webster thought that the three-syllable pronunciation was the only valid one, and that the proper pronunciation was obvious from the syllable breaks.

Comment: I generally hear a three-syllable pronunciation in British TV shows (I'm in the US), with the last syllable's vowel mostly turned into a schwa, to my ears. The most common US pronunciation, however, does seem to be two syllables. This may come down to dialect differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the pronunciation of "vacuum" has been simplified because it's become a widespread word in common use.  This is a bit less true of "continuum".  Also, the pronunciation of "continuum" may be influenced by that of "continue". (On Google Ngrams it can be seen that "vacuum" became much more common after 1900.  "Continuum" has also increased in popularity, but more recently and never reaching the same level.) "Vacuum" is commonly used in "vacuum cleaner", which is already four syllables with the shorter pronunciation of "vacuum".

The three-syllable pronunciation of "vacuum" is the only one in the Oxford English Dictionary (the online entry notes "This entry has not yet been fully updated (first published 1916)").  It is also the only one in the 1964 edition of the Concise Oxford Dictionary.

See also http://www.pbs.org/speak/speech/beastly/#Vacuum where Charles Harrington Elster claims that "with the advent of the vacuum cleaner in the early 20th century the three-syllable VAK-yoo-um swiftly became endangered".